# Ajax Click Event on auto refreshing HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an auto refreshing HTML table with some buttons in it.
I current use the folowing Code to Refresh the Table every 5 seconds and set the ajax ClickListener. My problem is that the event ONLY fire before the first refresh fired.

```html
<?php require_once ('UserTableHtml.php'); ?> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var table = $("#t02");

  // refresh every 5 seconds
  var refresher = setInterval(function() 
  {
    table.load("UserTableHtml.php");
  }, 5000);
                                                      
  table.ready(function()
  {
    $('.btnUser').click(function()
    {
      var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
      var ajaxurl = 'home.php',
      data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
      $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) 
      {
        // Response goes here.
        alert("action performed successfully");
      });
     });
   });
</script>
```

The complete code of the output table is generated by the 'UserTableHtml.php'

Thanks for your answers an MERRY CHRISTMAS

Comment: Have you tried using $('.btnUser').on('click',function(){...})?

Comment: Didn't get your question when you say "My problem is that the event ONLY fire before the first refresh fired.".. Did you mean that the the event listener / click works only after the first refresh...??

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with the click of the button, you should use

```
$('.btnUser').on('click',function(){...});
```

Insted of

```
$('.btnUser').click(function(){...});
```

For dynamic elements, attach events using the `.on()` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it only loads after 5 seconds... add the line below to have it load after the table has finished rendering.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var table = $("#t02");

  // refresh every 5 seconds
  var refresher = setInterval(function() 
  {
    table.load("UserTableHtml.php");
  }, 5000);

  table.ready(function()
  {
    $('.btnUser').click(function()
    {
      var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
      var ajaxurl = 'home.php',
      data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
      $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) 
      {
        // Response goes here.
        alert("action performed successfully");
      });
     });

     //add this here...
     table.load("UserTableHtml.php");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i just figured it out.
Now it works as excepted.

```js
var table = $("#t02");
table.ready(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.btnUser',function()
  {
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = 'home.php',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) 
    {
      // Response div goes here.
      alert("action performed successfully");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btnUser" name="userEdit" value="user_edit_'.$user->getId().'"><img src="images/edit-4.png" />
```

Comment: Is that what this guy said? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27639598/